# Rails how to create recursive nested_form_for for child-parent relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Model is

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_item
  has_many :menu_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :menu_items
end
```

How to create a form with ability to add dynamically children and also children of children if needed (preferably with nested_form_for). In other words form shall be something like:

```
input
  child input
    child input (child of child)
    add/remove child (child of child of child)
  add/remove child (child)
add/remove input
```

Clicking add/remove will add/remove one more according child, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use recursive partial views.

Items:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Item'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

shared/_items.html.erb:

```
<% items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="item" data-id="<%= item.id %>">
    <div class="content">
      <%= item.name %> <%= link_to 'Delete', item, :confirm => "Are you sure?", method: 'delete' %>
      <%= render partial: 'shared/items', locals: { items: item.children } if item.children %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Rendered items:

```
first Delete
    first a Delete
    first b Delete 
second Delete
    second a Delete
    second b Delete
    second c Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) should be able to handle your use case just fine. You will need to do some experimenting since deep nesting is non trivial.

Answer (score 0):

So, what You think about:

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "MenuItem", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many :childs, class_name: "MenuItem"
...
```